# Enlarge plot in popup window - Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to put an action button, to zoom and enlarge image on my shiny app. See the code below, the shiny app render two images "space_1.jpg" and "space_2.jpg" (already created), according to the choice of the user. The idea would be to allow the user the user to enlarge image in a popup window. I don't know how to make it possible. Many thanks for your help,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarPanel(width=6,
    radioButtons("choice", label = h4("Choose"),choices = c("space_1","space_2"), selected = "space_1"),
    dropdown(downloadButton(outputId = "down_image_test",label = "Download plot"),size = "xs",icon = icon("download", class = "opt"), up = TRUE),
    actionBttn(inputId = "zoom_image_test",icon = icon("search-plus", class = "opt"),style = "fill",color = "danger",size = "xs")
           ),

mainPanel(h2("main panel"),imageOutput('image_test'))

    )


server <- function(input, output){

    output$image_test <- renderImage({
        nam=paste0(getwd(),"/",input$choice,".jpg")
        list(src = nam,height = 200)}, deleteFile = FALSE)

    output$down_image_test <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "test.jpg",
        content = function(file) {
        nam=paste0(getwd(),"/",input$choice,".jpg")
        file.copy(nam, file)
    })  

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

The code is very corse, you can refine it yourself.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Enlarge Plot Demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("enlargeButton", "Enlarge")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$enlargeButton, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".modal-dialog { width: 100vw; }"))),
      plotOutput("enlargedPlot", height = "800px"),
    ))
    
    output$enlargedPlot <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```